# Get results with more than 1 different value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT [DesignGroupId], [dgc].[CustomerKey]
FROM [DesignGroupCustomer] AS [DGC]
INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [C] ON [DGC].[CustomerKey] = [C].[CustomerKey]
WHERE [C].[CustTypeKey] = 7
GROUP BY [DesignGroupId], [DGC].[CustomerKey]
ORDER BY [DesignGroupId]
```

It returns values as:

```
+--------------------------------------+------+
| A0E6E679-1CE3-4804-AF90-00022296CFA1 | 4644 |
| 0FFCFC8F-51EF-43FB-B2AE-000603ECC1EA | 4644 |
| 6CDC64F7-722C-4BA6-AE4E-0010F1C95F58 |  283 |
| 6CDC64F7-722C-4BA6-AE4E-0010F1C95F58 | 3832 |
+--------------------------------------+------+
```

That I want to do is to know what values have DesignGroups have different `CustomerKey`, so my desire result is to get only one row

```
6CDC64F7-722C-4BA6-AE4E-0010F1C95F58
```

because this Id have more than 1 different `CustomerKey`

I try to use HAVING COUNT like:

```
SELECT [DesignGroupId], [dgc].[CustomerKey]
FROM [DesignGroupCustomer] AS [DGC]
INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [C] ON [DGC].[CustomerKey] = [C].[CustomerKey]
WHERE [C].[CustTypeKey] = 7
GROUP BY [DesignGroupId], [DGC].[CustomerKey]
ORDER BY [DesignGroupId]
HAVING COUNT(DGC.CustomerKey) > 1
```

But it does not works, it is returning other values that I dont want. How can I achieve this? Regards

Comment: If you want one column (DesignGroupId), don't select other columns. Then adjust the GROUP BY and use HAVING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the customer key from the non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT [DesignGroupId]
FROM [DesignGroupCustomer] AS [DGC]
INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [C] ON [DGC].[CustomerKey] = [C].[CustomerKey]
WHERE [C].[CustTypeKey] = 7
GROUP BY [DesignGroupId]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [DGC].[CustomerKey]) > 1
```

I use `DISTNCT` in the count because it is unclear whether your sample data might contain duplicates on `DesignGroupId`/`CustomerKey`. If that's not the case, you can remove the `DISTINCT`.